# Limit SQLite table to have particular number of rows

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I've Sqlite Handler to save and fetch rows which contains some data. What I want is to limit the number of rows to 10 only at any given moment. Suppose there is already 10 rows added and I'm saving another row, it should delete the oldest row first entered and then insert the latest entry. I searched for it and the only answer I found is by creating a trigger. But there was no explanation of how to do this in SQLite. Is there any better way to do this?

```html
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "sammy_";

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

    // Profile Settings table name
    private static final String TABLE_ITEM = "item";

    // Profile Settings information names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
    private static final String KEY_APIID = "apiid";



    public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_PROF_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEM + "("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_TYPE+" TEXT, "+KEY_TITLE+" TEXT, "+KEY_SUBTITLE+" TEXT, "+KEY_APIID+" TEXT" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_PROF_TABLE);

        System.out.println("sammy_Database tables created");
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ITEM);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }


    /**
     * Storing Prof_settings details in database
     * */
    public void addContents(String type, String title, String subtitle, String apiid){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        values.put(KEY_SUBTITLE, subtitle);
        values.put(KEY_APIID, apiid);

        long id = db.insert(TABLE_ITEM, null, values); // insert to 1st row
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

        //Log.d(TAG, "New profile settings inserted into sqlite: " + id);
        System.out.println("sammy_New content inserted into sqlite: "+id);

    }




    /**
     * Getting data from database
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllContents()
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        //Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * " + " FROM " + TABLE_PROF + " GROUP BY " + KEY_NAME + " ORDER BY " + KEY_MOBILE + " COLLATE NOCASE;", null);
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ITEM;
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        res.moveToFirst();

        while (res.isAfterLast() == false)
        {
            HashMap<String, String> hashmap= new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashmap.put("type", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE)));
            hashmap.put("title", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE)));
            hashmap.put("subtitle", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_SUBTITLE)));
            hashmap.put("apiid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(KEY_APIID)));

            array_list.add(hashmap);
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }

    /**
     * Re create database Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void deleteContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_ITEM, null, null);
        db.close();
        System.out.println("sammy_Deleted all contents from sqlite");
        //Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all profile info from sqlite");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you not attempt to clean your database when inserting the new records.  Instead, just store a timestamp for each record, and when you need the most recent 10 just use:

```
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10
```

One option for keeping track of the 10 most recent entries in your app Java code would be to use [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), which can be configured to retain only the 10 most recent entries.

Comment: Well, if I can't limit the rows, can I simply fetch the latest 10 records using `getAllContents` method and LinkedHashMap? I mean do I have to add timestamp to the table also? @Tim

Comment: Yes, add the timestamp to the table, which won't cost you much.  Also, look into `LinkedHashMap#removeEldestEntry` to see if that might suit your needs.

Comment: It´s a good a approach, but just for interest, why not deleting the oldest entry? What´s the disadvantage if this entries are not needed anymore?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs He can create a background job to delete those stale entries.  It doesn't have to be done on the spot.  Instead, I am advocating a soft delete.

Answer (score 0):

@Sam,

Dude assuming you want only 10 records in your table what you can do is while adding new record take a count if it is equal to 10 you can delete the first record (old record) depending on your primary key in your case i think its `id`

so create a function which return a count

```
public int getProfilesCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int cnt = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return cnt;
}
```

since your not using any timestamp field what you do is to decide the oldest record based on your `id` since it is `primary key`

so inside your `addContents` function add the code i have given inside comment

```
/**
 * Storing Prof_settings details in database
 * */
public void addContents(String type, String title, String subtitle, String apiid){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    values.put(KEY_SUBTITLE, subtitle);
    values.put(KEY_APIID, apiid);
    // the code you have to add
    int count = getProfilesCount(); // check for number of records
    if(count == 10) {
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " ORDER BY  "+KEY_ID+"LIMIT 1"); // will delete oldest record
    } // add till here

    long id = db.insert(TABLE_ITEM, null, values); // insert to 1st row
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    //Log.d(TAG, "New profile settings inserted into sqlite: " + id);
    System.out.println("sammy_New content inserted into sqlite: "+id);

}
```

Comment: I'm getting `SQLiteException: near "ORDER": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM item ORDER BY  idLIMIT 1` @eLemEnt

Comment: give space between id and LIMIT 1 @sam

Answer (score 0):

I think trigger is the best answer to this question.

[This is the sample tutorial for how to make trigger in android.](http://www.coderconsole.com/2015/02/android-sqlite-trigger-demo.html)

Add your logic there.

Comment: A trigger can't act on the table which fired it in SQLite, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do like your query.

1. Fist one is that, handle that one get total no of rows and check, if these are more that 10, then first delete an older row and then run the insert command else directly execute the insert command.
2. Second one is that instead of handling this condition by your self give it to the trigger it will automatically handle this situation
   out of these two ways second one is better because, no of database hits matters in performance so in case of trigger there will be only one hit to the data base.